# how to display all values of a duplicate key in hashmap with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem concerning my hashMap in JS. I have some properties "keys" that are repeated several times but at least in my hashMap I find only the last one.

Example : let suppose we have this list of keys `( 12345, 12346, 12346, 12346, 12347)` and for each one I attribute some values

```
12345 <= 1
12346 <= 2
12346 <= 1
12346 <= 3
12347 <= 4
```

At the final it displays : `12345 : 1, 12346:3 , 12347:4` . But I need also those informations `12346 : 1, 12346 : 2` in my HashMap.

Here is my code :

```
getFacing: function(iSceneGraph){
                var facingArray = {};
                if (iSceneGraph.children.length >0){
                    for (var i = 0; i < iSceneGraph.children.length; i++){
                        facingArray = Object.assign(facingArray, this.getFacing(iSceneGraph.children[i]));
                    }
                }
                if (iSceneGraph.merch.type === "Facing"){
                    facingArray[iSceneGraph.merch.ean] = iSceneGraph.merch.hcount;
                }
                return facingArray;
            }
```

---

Result :

I want to display my hashmap this way cause it's the best solution :

```
12345 : 1
12346 : {2,1,3}
12347 : 4
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It is impossible for the object to have same key multiple times. You should have an array and push the items into it.

Comment: I thought the purpose of a hashmap is that every item has a unique identifier. Maybe you should change your data structure.

Comment: @DavidDomain you're right, but the goal here is to have a key with an array of values. So it could work, but I don't know how to change this method

Comment: How are you creating the hashmap where there are duplicate hashes?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody it's a JSON

Answer (score 1):

Since items can not be repeated, you need to store an array of values for the key. Below is a simple demo showing how you can loop over an array and transfer it into what I think you are after.

```js
var testData = [
  {key: "item1", value: 1},
  {key: "item2", value: 2},
  {key: "item3", value: 3},
  {key: "item1", value: 4},
  {key: "item2", value: 5}
]

var out = testData.reduce( function (obj, itm) {
   if (!obj[itm.key]) obj[itm.key] = [];  //see if we found this before, if not set it
   obj[itm.key].push(itm.value);  //push the value
   return obj  //return the object
}, {}) 

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it's a little far away from my case. Precisely, i parse a JSON and for each time i set the hashMap , i can't use your solution because from the beggining i don't have duplicate keys. Have a look in my function

Comment: The logic is the same.

Comment: Can u explain pls?

Comment: another information, i'll explain u step by step what happens in my function.. for each type facing i catch the ean and I attribute as value the hcount.. So the problem, is for example he found 12345 and he attributes 3 , then he founds again 12345 and crush the last value but I want to keep all the values he meets.. for the moment I dont have values like u did so it won't work .

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [12345, 12346, 12346, 12346, 12347];
var MoMap = new Map()
var count = 1;
for (let i of arr) {
  if (MoMap.has(i)) {
    var val = MoMap.get(i)
    count++;
    val.push(count)
  } else MoMap.set(i, [1])
}

console.log(...MoMap)
```

Comment: @BBenkaddour does this answer your question or do you need something more nuanced?

Comment: i'll explain u step by step what happens in my function.. for each type facing i catch the ean and I attribute as value the hcount.. So the problem, is for example he found 12345 and he attributes 3 , then he founds again 12345 and crush the last value but I want to keep all the values he meets.. for the moment I dont have values like u did so it won't work .

Comment: @BBenkaddour However, those values are not in the original data set you provided, can you provide the data set you are working on so that the pattern can be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hash = [
    { key: 12345,
      value: 1
    }, {
      key: 12347,
      value: 2
    }, {
      key: 12347,
      value: 3
    }, {
      key: 12347,
      value: 7
    }];

function getFacing() {
      let result = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
        const element = hash[i];
        let index = result.findIndex(elem => elem.key === element.key);
        if (index === -1) {
          result.push({
            key: element.key,
            value: [element.value]
          });
        } else {
          result[index].value.push(element.value);
        }
      }

      return result;
    }
```

**getFacing** returns [{12345: [1]}, {12347: [2,3,7]}]